# SAPUI5 Application - Session

Tags: session, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 application on my SAP Portal. 
I need to get the SAP Portal user logon on my application SAPUI5.
 How can I do it?

Comment: What do you have so far? The people will help you, but won't read the documentation for you. So, please, put a little more effort into your work.

Comment: My apllicattion SAPUI5 is ready, I Just need learn how get the Session of the SAP Portal

Comment: Please check these two links: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3597886 and https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/09/securing-sap-ui5-task-ui-applications-also-resolves-log-on-issues/

Comment: HI Rahul, thank for help.

My ui5 is deployed to nw portal, and I need get the nw user Logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ` var oUserData;
      var y = "/sap/bc/ui2/start_up"; 
      var xmlHttp = null;
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
      oUserData = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText); 
      } 
      };
      xmlHttp.open("GET", y, false);
      xmlHttp.send(null);`
```

console oUserData to get login details of that user who logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the SAPUI5 user API as detailed here: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/04/16/using-the-hcp-user-api-in-web-ide/ - I don't recommend the xmlhttprequest method.

The steps are:
- Add route to existing routes in neo-app.json:

```
"routes": [
......
  {
    "path":"/services/userapi",
    "target":{
        "type":"service",
        "name":"userapi"
    }
  }
]
```

Then create and set a JSONModel to call/store the results of the service (generally I set it to the Component in the Component.js init method):

```
var userModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("/services/userapi/currentUser");
this.setModel(userModel, "user");
```

Once the model loads, you will have the following fields in the "user" model:

- name
- firstName
- lastName
- displayName
- email

An example of using this in a view would look like:

```
<Text text="{user>/name}"/>
```

Or getting it at runtime in the controller:

```
var userName = this.getModel("user").getProperty("/name");
```

There is an additional variant for getting user attributes where your JSONModel instantiation string is: `"/services/userapi/attributes?multiValuesAsArrays=true"`